# Ternary Operators confusion in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and have been learning through an online course. Why can I use a ternary operator inside a JSX expression but not an if statement?

Answer (score 3):

According to [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).

JSX just provides syntactic sugar for the `React.createElement(component, props, ...children)` function.

```
ReactDOM.render(<div id="message">Hello Darren!</div>, mountNode);
```

It will be converted into this.

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement("div", {id:"message"}, "Hello Darren!"), mountNode);
```

So if we try to put `if` in jsx.

```
<div id={if (condition) { 'message' }}>Hello Darren!</div>
```

It will come up like this in jsx.

```
React.createElement("div", {id: if (condition) { 'message' }}, "Hello Darren!");
```

And that's why ternary is used.

```
ReactDOM.render(<div id={condition ? 'message' : null}>Hello Darren!</div>, mountNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of javascript will render within jsx if it is an *expression* -- that is, if it resolves to a particular value. A standalone `if` is a javascript control *statement*, but not an *expression*, and doesn't by itself resolve to a value.

So to use it within jsx, it needs to contribute somehow to a greater expression -- for example it might determine the output of an *immediately invoked function expression* (iife), which can resolve to (return) a value. Example:

```
<p>
{(() => {
   if(something)
      return "some text"
   else
      return "some other text"
})()}
</p>
```

Here's a not-too-bad explaination of the [differences between expressions and statements in javascript](http://%20https://2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html)